# Managing RavenDB IDocumentSession lifecycles with StructureMap for NServiceBus and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb, nservicebus, structuremap

I am using NServiceBus v4.3, MVC4, RavenDB 2.5 and StructureMap 2.6.4 in our solution.

I am having a similar issue under StructureMap to that described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774386/managing-ravendb-session-in-windsor-under-nservicebus)'s [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563256/2582424) where I require different lifecycles for the MVC Controller and NServiceBus Handler use of RavenDB's IDocumentSession in my Web project.

Specifically in my case what happens is that if I use the HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped (as the above answer suggests for Windsor) lifecycle the sessions are not properly disposed of and I soon hit the 30 transaction limit error. If I use the HttpContext lifecycle my NSB event Handlers in the Web project do not get called.

In my Controllers the session is wrapped in a unit of work applied via an MVC ActionFilter. I also use the UoW within the Handlers as my Registry is wired up to retrieve the session from the UoW. The code is as such:

RavenDbWebRegistry.cs

```
public sealed class RavenDbWebRegistry : Registry
{
    public RavenDbWebRegistry()
    {
        // register RavenDB document store
        ForSingletonOf<IDocumentStore>().Use(() =>
        {
            var documentStore = new DocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB",
                Conventions =
                {
                    IdentityPartsSeparator = "-", 
                    JsonContractResolver = new PrivatePropertySetterResolver(),
                },

            };
            documentStore.Initialize();

            return documentStore;
        });


        For<IDocumentSession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Add(ctx =>
        {
            var uow = (IRavenDbUnitOfWork)ctx.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
            return uow.DocumentSession;
        });

        For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<WebRavenDbUnitOfWork>();            

    }
}
```

Example of Web project Handler:

```
public class SiteCreatedEventHandler : IHandleMessages<ISiteCreatedEvent>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }
    public IUnitOfWork Uow { get; set; }
    public IDocumentSession DocumentSession { get; set; }

    public void Handle(ISiteCreatedEvent message)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Print(@"{0}{1}", message, Environment.NewLine);

            Uow.Begin();
            var site = DocumentSession.Load<Site>(message.SiteId);
            Uow.Commit();

            //invoke Hub and push update to screen
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlarmAndNotifyHub>();

            //TODO make sure this SignalR function is correct
            context.Clients.All.displayNewSite(site, message.CommandId);
            context.Clients.All.refreshSiteList();            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            Uow.Rollback();
        }            
    }
}
```

Usage of ActionFilter:

```
    [RavenDbUnitOfWork]
    public ViewResult CreateNew(int? id)
    {
        if (!id.HasValue || id.Value <= 0)
            return View(new SiteViewModel { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() });

        var targetSiteVm = MapSiteToSiteViewModel(SiteList(false)).FirstOrDefault(s => s.SiteId == id.Value);

        return View(targetSiteVm);
    }
```

WebRegistry (that sets up NSB in my MVC project)

```
public sealed class WebRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebRegistry()
    {
        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.TheCallingAssembly();
            x.Assembly("IS.CommonLibrary.ApplicationServices");
            x.LookForRegistries();
        });

        IncludeRegistry<RavenDbWebRegistry>();

        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IUnitOfWork>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IDocumentSession>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<StatusConversionService>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IStateRepository<TieState>>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IStateRepository<DedState>>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<ITieService>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IDedService>();
        FillAllPropertiesOfType<IHbwdService>();

        //NServiceBus
        ForSingletonOf<IBus>().Use(
        NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Command"))
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Event"))
            .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace == "Messages")
            .RavenPersistence("RavenDB")
            .UseTransport<ActiveMQ>()
            .DefineEndpointName("IS.Argus.Web")
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() => NServiceBus.Configure.Instance
            .ForInstallationOn<Windows>()
            .Install())
        );


        //Web             
        For<HttpContextBase>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current == null ? null : new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
        For<ModelBinderMappingDictionary>().Use(GetModelBinders());
        For<IModelBinderProvider>().Use<StructureMapModelBinderProvider>();
        For<IFilterProvider>().Use<StructureMapFilterProvider>();
        For<StatusConversionService>().Use<StatusConversionService>();
        For<ITieService>().Use<TieService>();
        For<IDedService>().Use<DedService>();
        For<IHbwdService>().Use<HbwdService>();
        For<ISiteService>().Use<SiteService>();

        IncludeRegistry<RedisRegistry>();
    }
```

I have tried configuring my Registry using every possible combination I can think of to no avail.

Given that the StructureMap hybrid lifecycle does not work as I would expect, what must I do to achieve the correct behaviour?

Is the UoW necessary/beneficial with RavenDB? I like it (having adapted it from my earlier NHibernate UoW ActionFilter) because of the way it manages the lifecycle of my sessions within Controller Actions, but am open to other approaches.

What I would ideally like is a way to - within the Web project - assign entirely different IDocumentSessions to Controllers and Handlers, but have been unable to work out any way to do so.

Comment: Must you use StructureMap?  We do exactly what you're trying to do, but with Ninject.  It's actually pretty trivial with Ninject.  We looked at StructureMap and decided to pass on it in favor of Ninject.  If you're willing and/or able to use Ninject, I'll be able to provide a complete solution for you.

Comment: We're pretty invested in StructureMap by now unfortunately; however I have seen how it's done using NInject and wish StructureMap was as accommodating!
We ended up refactoring around the issue, but thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, RavenDB already implements unit of work by the wrapping `IDocumentSession`, so no need for it. Opening a session, calling `SaveChanges()` and disposing has completed the unit of work

Secondly, Sessions can be implemented in a few ways for controllers.

The general guidance is to set up the store in the `Global.asax.cs`. Since there is only 1 framework that implements `IDocumentSession` - RavenDB, you might as well instantiate it from the `Global`. If it was NHibernate or Entity Framework behind a repository, I'd understand. But IDocumentSession is RavenDB specific, so go with a direct initialization in the `Application_Start`.

```cs
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
   public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // Usual MVC stuff

      // This is your Registry equivalent, so insert it into your Registry file 
      ObjectFactory.Initialize(x=> 
      {
         x.For<IDocumentStore>()
          .Singleton()
          .Use(new DocumentStore { /* params here */ }.Initialize());
   }

   public void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var store = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>();

      if(store!=null)
         store.Dispose();
   }
}
```

In the Controllers, add a base class and then it can open and close the sessions for you. Again `IDocumentSession` is specific to RavenDB, so dependency injection doesn't actually help you here.

```cs
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
   protected IDocumentSession Session { get; private set; }

   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
      Session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession();
   }

   protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
   {
      if(this.IsChildAction)
         return;

      if(content.Exception != null && Session != null)
         using(context)
            Session.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Then from there, inherit from the base controller and do your work from there:

```cs
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
   public ActionResult Get(string id)
   {
      var customer = Session.Load<Customer>(id);

      return View(customer);
   }

   public ActionResult Edit(Customer c)
   {
      Session.Store(c);

      return RedirectToAction("Get", c.Id);
   }
 }
```

---

Finally, I can see you're using StructureMap, so it only takes a few basic calls to get the Session from the DI framework:

```cs
public class SiteCreatedEventHandler : IHandleMessages<ISiteCreatedEvent>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }
    public IUnitOfWork Uow { get; set; }
    public IDocumentSession DocumentSession { get; set; }

    public SiteCreatedEventHandler()
    {
       this.DocumentSession = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession();
    }

    public void Handle(ISiteCreatedEvent message)
    {
       using(DocumentSession)
       {
          try
          {
             Debug.Print(@"{0}{1}", message, Environment.NewLine);

             ///// Uow.Begin(); // Not needed for Load<T>

             var site = DocumentSession.Load<Site>(message.SiteId);

             //// Uow.Commit(); // Not needed for Load<T>

             // invoke Hub and push update to screen
             var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlarmAndNotifyHub>();

             // TODO make sure this SignalR function is correct
             context.Clients.All.displayNewSite(site, message.CommandId);
             context.Clients.All.refreshSiteList();            
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {                
             //// Uow.Rollback(); // Not needed for Load<T>
         }            
      }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't querying the IoC container kind of negate the benefits of DI in the first place? I may be missing the point of your post, but these calls into `ObjectFactory.GetInstance` look more like the [service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) anti-pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `SiteCreatedEventHandler` is created, or if whatever is creating it supports DI. Its only for reference, and so should be adapted to suit the framework instantiating the instance of the handler.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but SiteCreatedEventHandler is an NServiceBus MessageHandler - we don't have any issues managing IDocumentSession simply within MVC, or simply within NSB Handlers for that matter, but only in our MVC project that also hosts an NSB Bus instance.
It is the different scopes that are required by MVC as opposed to the NSB Handlers that is the sole cause of the issue.
We ended up just refactoring around it and passing a couple of extra parameters in our Event Message to avoid needing the IDocumentSession from the Handlers within the MVC project.

Comment: Regarding the use of a base controller, the UoW is actually built around avoiding that - it's an ActionFilter so can be applied to individual Actions or entire Controllers as required without injecting an IDocumentSession into every controller, even when one is unnecessary.